# Can't get watchdog to kick on freeRTOS application using S32K mcu

Tags: c, freertos, watchdog, nxp-microcontroller

Using the S32K146 MCU with DS for ARM v2.2.

After I initialize my WDOG, I can confirm that it is working to reset the system... but I cannot seem to successfully kick the WDOG. It just keeps resetting the system.

Here is my WDOG config:

```
#include "watchdog1.h"

/*! watchdog1 configuration structure */
const wdog_user_config_t watchdog1_Config0 = {
    .clkSource = WDOG_LPO_CLOCK,       /* WDOG clock source */
    .opMode = {
        false,                         /* Wait Mode         */
        false,                         /* Stop Mode         */
        false                           /* Debug Mode        */
    },
    .updateEnable = true,              /* Enable/Disable further updates of the WDOG configuration */
    .intEnable = true,                /* Timeout interrupt disabled */
    .winEnable = false,                /* Enable/Disable Window mode */
    .windowValue = 0U,                 /* Window value               */
    .timeoutValue = 9000U,             /* Timeout value              */
    .prescalerEnable = true            /* WDOG prescaler             */
};
```

... and I use these two wrapper functions for the NXP API to init and try to kick the WDOG:

```
void init_watchdog(void) {
    /* Initialize the WDOG driver */
    WDOG_DRV_Init(INST_WATCHDOG1, &watchdog1_Config0);
}

void refresh_watchdog(void) {
    WDOG_DRV_Trigger(INST_WATCHDOG1);
}
```

My application is FreeRTOS based. I inserted the WDOG init call in main along with my other initializations.
I have a UART print in main that shows me when the system is reset.

The issue is that regardless of where I call `refresh_watchdog()`, I cannot get the WDOG timer to reset.
Currently, I enabled `#define configUSE_IDLE_HOOK 1` in FreeRTOS config so I can use the idle task with `void vApplicationIdleHook(void)` to call the wdog kick. Still no luck.

Wdog is working to reset the system, I just need to know how I can successfully kick the thing.
I have multiple RTOS tasks with different priorities, running with a semaphore based ISR routine.
Any ideas?

I tried refreshing the watchdog:

- In my RTOS tasks just after the while(1) call or at the end of the task. (No luck)
- Tried calling WDOG reset in the ISR function. (I shouldn't do this anyways, but no luck)
- I tried creating a new independent RTOS task that just contains the reset function and kicks the WDOG when it gets passed the semaphore. (no luck)

Comment: If the WDG resets the MCU, it means that it was not kicked in time. Add some trace before you call this function and see what is going on.

Comment: Right, so I set the WDOG reset to 15+ seconds... which should be plenty of time. Still no luck resetting. What would you implement to trace?

Comment: even toggle the pin and see it on your scope or logic analyzer, send char via uart, use ITC interface - it does not matter. Simply see what is going on. Most likely you have a deadlock in your RTOS code. When I hear multiple priorities - I am getting suspicious

Comment: `false                           /* Debug Mode        */` Does that mean that it is running in debug mode, or sleeping in debug mode?